# So how can I listen to an event in a Vue component, emitted from another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have my app.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import ProductsGrid from './components/ProductsGrid.vue';
import Cart from './components/Cart.vue';
import NavLink from './components/NavLink.vue';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';

const app = createApp({
  components: {
    'products-grid': ProductsGrid,
    'cart': Cart,
  }
});

app.mount('#app');
```

my product grid component just lists the items fetched from an api. each item has a "buy" button.
When you press a button, it emits this buy event:

```
        buy(product) {
            this.$emit('buy', product);
            console.log("buy event triggered on produt "+product.id);
        },
```

the text and the given product are shown in the console log.

But I want to add them to the cart, which is a separate component. How am I supposed to do that?
I know you can listen to an event in the same component with `v-on` (or `@`smth), but this doesn't work in my case.

The cart component is just this:

```
addProductToCart(product) {
            console.log(product+" product received by products grid component");
        },
```

How am I supposed to listen to an event from another component?
Or am I doing it the wrong way?

I'm using these in a laravel project, so these vue components are used in blade templates.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you need to use a store to store the cart data. The recommended store for vue3 is pinia : https://pinia.vuejs.org/ 
The store will allow to share the cart data between differents components.

Comment: So I can't do it with just vuejs and laravel, right?

Comment: You can probably do it, but you'll have a lot of interaction between your different components to share the data.
It would be a better idea to have a centralised place where your store your cart data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vue 3 - Event bus

From what I see you are using the latest version of `Vue.js` (`3.x`).
As stated here https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#migration-strategy, the global event bus is removed in Vue 3 (`this.$emit` is still available for child -> parent communication).

In order to implement a global Event bus for different components in app to communicate with events, you need an external package such as [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt).
The implementation is easy if you follow the examples. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event bus to handle this case

Create event bus inside main.js

```
...
export const eventBus  = new Vue();
...
```

In component A.vue (emit event through event bus)

```
import {eventBus} from "../main.js"

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    buy: function(product) {
      eventBus.＄emit("buy-product", product);
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

In component B.vue (listen event emitted from event bus)

```
import { eventBus } from "../main";
export default {
  ...
  created: function() {
    eventBus.＄on("buy-product", (product) => {
      console.log("product received from event bus " + product.id);
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
      eventBus.＄off("buy-product");
  }
 ...
};
```

Comment: Looks like reinventing jquery